# How to decode the image from json object?

Tags: android, json, bitmap

I am trying to post the image in Base64 format string to the web server. And I need to retrieve it back from the web server and decode it in Bitmap format so that I can display the image in listview.But I am getting the error while decoding.
 Please take a look at the code I've posted here..

Encoding:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, byteArrayBitmapStream);
byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = MyBase64.encode(b);
```

Decoding:

```
byte[] byteArray =  Base64.decode(jsonObject.getString("imageData"), Base64.DEFAULT) ;
System.out.println("byte[]:"+byteArray);
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Here is the log:![Error showing in logcat]

```
12-12 06:09:12.243: E/BitmapFactory(1037): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@40cd85a8: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 06:09:12.243: I/System.out(1037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40cd85a8
12-12 06:09:12.313: E/BitmapFactory(1037): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@40ce3620: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 06:09:12.313: I/System.out(1037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40ce3620
12-12 06:09:12.393: E/BitmapFactory(1037): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@40ef8fc0: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 06:09:12.393: I/System.out(1037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40ef8fc0
12-12 06:09:12.473: E/BitmapFactory(1037): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@40cf2588: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 06:09:12.473: I/System.out(1037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40cf2588
12-12 06:09:12.533: E/BitmapFactory(1037): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@40cd6060: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 06:09:12.533: I/System.out(1037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40cd6060
12-12 06:09:12.613: E/BitmapFactory(1037): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@40eefc68: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 06:09:12.613: I/System.out(1037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40eefc68
```

Comment: This link is Usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767615/how-to-display-image-byte-array-from-json-into-imageview-factory-returns-nu

Comment: and you are getting this error while decoding or encoding?

Comment: @M-WaJeEh I am getting this error while decoding.Please help me out.

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan Hi,thank u for providing the link. But that is not working for me.Please guide me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

hey u want to decode image from json object

then u first store image url in database and access by json

then than get bitmap image from url

use following code

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is a loop